# Adding Curreny Format to NoUISlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, currency

I am using nouislider (http://refreshless.com/nouislider/), but what I am trying to do is have the value outputted from the slider come out looking like this:

£3,500

Rather than:

3500

So far my code is as follows:

```
<script>
    var slider = $('#sample-update-slider');
    slider.noUiSlider({
        range: [250, 75000],
        start: 11500,
        handles: 1,
        margin: 2,
        step: 250,
        serialization: {
            to: [$('#value'), 'text'],
            resolution: 1
        }    
    });
</script>
```

For any of you that are familiar with nouislider, the value is outputted to a span with an ID of value.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks

Dave

Thank you for anyone who looked at this question, I have answer part of it with the help of the developer of nouislider, but he seems to be a busy guy so he hasn't given me the full answer.

so far i have been able to add the currency to the number with the following script:

```
var slider = $('#totaldebt');

slider.noUiSlider({
range: [250, 75000]
,start: 14500
,handles: 1
,margin: 2
,step: 250
,serialization: {
to: function( value ) {
 var value = "£" + value;
$('#totaldebt-value').text( value );
}    ,resolution: 1

}

});
```

The code that adds the currency to the output is:

```
to: function( value ) {
var value = "£" + value;
$('#totaldebt-value').text( value );
}
```

My other problem is separating the numbers that are greater than 1000 with commas, so 1000 becomes 1,000.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I used this function in my script:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
 return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Then my nouislider code:

```
$slider.noUiSlider({
range: [80000,1000000],
start: [250000],
step: [sliderStep],
connect: "lower",
handles: 1,
serialization: {
  to: function(value){

   value = "£" + numberWithCommas(value);    
   $("#value").val(value);

   }
}
});
```